# Mongoose error : Cannot read property 'pluralization' of null

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I've just started learning Nodejs and i've been trying to create a schema to store emails and passwords but when i start server.js i get this

```
d:\Make your CV\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:357
ion' in schema.options)) schema.options.pluralization = this.options.pluraliza
                                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluralization' of null
at Mongoose.model (d:\Make your CV\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:357:88)
at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Make your CV\makecv.js:19:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

and this is **makecv.js**

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();
var ECT = require('ect');
var ectRenderer = ECT({ watch: true, root: __dirname + '/views', ext : '.ect' });
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sam');

var db = mongoose.Connection();

var UserSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    email : String,
    password : String
});

// create the model for users
 var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);  //line 19

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //line 21

 app.use(bodyParser.json())

 app.set('view engine', 'ect');
 app.engine('ect', ectRenderer.render);

 app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
 var email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
 var password = req.body.password;
 var user = new User();
 user.email = email;
 bcrypt.hash(password, null, null, function(err, hpassword) {
 // Store hash in your password DB.
 user.password = hpassword;
 });
 user.save(function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.redirect('/');
     });
 });


app.listen(8080);
```

I know the code is kind of a mess, but i'm still learning.

Comment: What is `var db = mongoose.Connection();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var UserSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
email : String,
password : String
}, { collection: 'User'});
```

or

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');
```

because mongoose pluralize the collection, and it looks `users` Collection in your database

check this [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#utils_exports.pluralization)

you have forgot `new` when you declare `mongoose.Schema({`

I don't understand what is

```
var db = mongoose.Connection();
```

maybe you want something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/sam';

// Create the database connection
var db = mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// Define connection events
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
        console.log('Mongoose disconnected through app termination');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

with hook..
Anyway [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/qRW4A/1/) I've commented some library because i haven’t these

I hope to help you